# Why VMware DHCP persists getting offline?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vmware, dhcp

I am trying to set up a SSH server in my remote machine which is running Windows 7 on it currently. So first I set up a Oracle VirtualBox but it did not work for me properly. Then I decided to go with VMware instead of dealing with the problems of the VirtualBox.

I installed VMware, installed an Ubuntu Virtual Machine inside. It is now working like a charm. But I have a problem. It gets disconnected after a while. As you can see below, it is disconnected. And it can get started to work properly again only if I switch manually to Vmnet8 and back to vmnet0 again. In the end (after performing the switching process) It takes a random Subnet address everytime it gets connected.

My problem is I need to have always the same Subnet address everytime I get connected and set the system so that it never gets disconnected. So that I connect to the machine via SSH using putty without getting into settings and port forwarding processes and everything at everytime that I need to connect.

[image: Problem Screnshot]

Answer (score 0):

Since this is bridged, it might be that you get disconnects if there is something else with the same mac address as whatever VMNet0 has. I think it can also get disconnected if there is another host with the same IP.

To always have the the same IP, you would configure the DHCP server so that when it sees the mac address that for the VMNet0 it assigns an IP that you tell DHCP to give out.